# Google Contacts force-closes

Tags: crashes, google-contacts

I just bought a new LG Nexus 5X. Stock 6.0.1, not rooted. For some reason, Google Contacts has been force-closing. Clearing its cache & data did not resolve it. I can't reproduce the issue in Safe Mode, so apparently it's caused by a 3rd party app. The only apps that have the ability to update contact information are Google Plus & Facebook Messenger. I tried uninstalling both, but the problem still occurred.

I also have Google Contacts installed on my LG G3 with all the same apps and it works fine. When I set up my 5X, I imported apps & data from my G3. I tried a factory reset yesterday and restored apps & data from my most recent Google backup of the device with no joy.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention I'm able to access and edit my contacts via the contacts tab in  Google Phone just fine.

I took a bug report, here's the crash info. No idea what it means. I hope someone has an idea.

```
------ SYSTEM LOG (logcat -v threadtime -d *:v) ------
--------- beginning of crash
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.contacts, PID: 24506
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.action.QUICK_CONTACT flg=0x4000000 pkg=com.google.android.contacts (has extras) }
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.action.QUICK_CONTACT flg=0x4000000 pkg=com.google.android.contacts (has extras) }
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1798)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.contacts.common.util.ImplicitIntentsUtil.startActivityInApp(ImplicitIntentsUtil.java:75)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity.processIntent(PeopleActivity.java:294)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity.onCreate(PeopleActivity.java:233)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
07-11 17:18:54.398 24506 24506 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
07-11 17:24:34.384 28315 28653 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3829
07-11 17:24:34.384 28315 28653 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.paranoidgems.potential, PID: 28315
07-11 17:24:34.384 28315 28653 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
07-11 17:24:34.384 28315 28653 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.paranoidgems.potential.i.run(BatteryStatusBroadcastReceiver.java:541)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Nova Launcher shortcut to Contacts. I removed the shortcut and added it again and all is well. I kinda feel dumb now.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services is my suspected culprit. It has had some issues since the new update. Try clearing its cache and data. It may sign you out of any app that uses Google as login authentication, but may do the trick.

Comment: Whst issues have you experienced? If it were Google Play Services, wouldn't the crash still happen in Safe Mode? As I mentioned, I can't reproduce the issue in Safe Mode.